# How to debug a Lambda function in Cloud9?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, aws-lambda, cloud9-ide, aws-sam

How do I debug a Lambda function in Cloud9 ? I tried to debug a file with a lambda and it started but lambda itself has not been invoked. What is the proper way to do this?

[image]

This is screen of function based on SAM init hello world application.

This is definition of resource from template.yaml:

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
```

Comment: There is no lanmbda here. You just have a function called `lambda_xxxx`. And you never call that function.

Comment: With SAM I should be able to debug serverless apps locally and lambda definition is in template.yaml

Comment: your `CodeUri` and event `Path` are different

Comment: The template file is autogenerated and is correct. CodeUri is for the lambda code and Path is for the http endpoint